# Drywall repair - trying to match texture

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

There was a leak. And a hole made in the ceiling to solder the pipe. I attempted to repair the drywall and am having an issue with the texture. Interesting to note, if I turn on the ceiling lights, this is barely noticable. The color difference is due to the spotlight I used to take the picture. Once done, the whole ceiling will be painted.

For now, my question is what process/technique is used to get the less rough finish? I don't even know how to ask the question if I went to a hardware store. I'm assuming there's a tool that will give me a finer stroke than the drywall tools I used.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a finer/softer touch.  Texture matching is more of an art form than tool use.

Comment: https://youtu.be/9l02eMhsRpQ — decent video

Comment: I think your texture might be described as a stomp. Use a crowsfoot brush and pull down. That said, texture (especially this) is really tough.

Comment: Thanks, watching his videos now.

Comment: I think your first problem is getting the base even with the rest of the drywall.  I can see your repair is "lower" than the surrounding texture.

Comment: Good eye. Now, when I add more joint compound to adjust the texture, I'll also look to level it better. The Drywall I added must have been 1/8" thinner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That texture is done with a paint brush.
Make what you have smooth.
Apply compound and use a paint brush the width of the swirls and swooshes you have originally.
Use a light touch and move the brush in the compound at about a 15 degree angle.
The bristles will make the high and low "canals"
Practice on some scrap first.
Varying the pressure on the brush will make the patterns more random.
I think you will find swiping the brush in an arc and lifting it while still moving will closely replicate that finish.
Good Luck...Practice...Practice...Practice.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll take your advice and practice on scrap drywall first.

Answer (score 2):

RMDman had some good thoughts.

Another thing to consider:  the lighter color your paint, the less noticeable any texture imperfections will be.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good results with a sponge in a plastic bag for this effect.

If you've used a trowel or float before you may have experienced the float 'sticking' to the material; it feels like suction, it's difficult to pull the float directly off, so you have to slide in one direction pulling at the same time. The floated finish is not dissimilar to the photo you provided.
So replace the float for a sponge at least the size of a small float, place inside a bag, apply finish evenly, press the sponge into finish; not at an angle, but flat/parallel to the surface, then move it in the direction you want the swirl, lifting gently at the same time. You will need to practice this on some spare material to perfect your technique.

Comment: Thank-you. I'll practice this one if the brush isn't close to what I'm looking for. I don't need a perfect result, I know a nice thick coat of paint will cut down on the difference in look. Good enough is good enough.